# 2-rank of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a symmetric integral matrix with zero diagonal, then I want to prove $2-rank(A)$ (i.e. the dimension of $C_A$ ) is even?

$2-rank(A)$ means dimension A on field $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: **Hint:** Reduce your matrix modulo 2, and find the determinant (modulo 2, of course).  What can you say if the determinant is 1? What can you say if it is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$ a symmetric matrix with zero diagonal values is actually a skew symmetric matrix since $1 \equiv -1 \mod(2)$. It is easier to prove that a (real) skew symmetric matrix of odd dimension has zero determinant.

Comment: I suppose that symmetric is the same as skew symmetric in $\mathbb{F}_2$ really, but for this problem focus on the skew symmetric attribute.

Comment: A $ 1 \times 1$ matrix is symmetric, and (in $\mathbb{F}_2$) skew symmetric with determinant of $0$ or $1$, but if it has a zero diagonal, it must be the $1 \times 1$ matrix $0$, and it has determinant of $0$.